# What size is the Kenwood TM-D710 panel mounting bracket?

Tags: mobile, kenwood, installation

For the purposes of this question, I am considering purchasing a Kenwood TM-D710GA (or a RC-D710). The control panel has a mounting bracket for mobile use which is intended to be attached to a flat surface, but I haven't found any description of how large the bracket is so I can tell whether it will fit where I have in mind.

What are the dimensions of this bracket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This image of the bottom side of the bracket was taken with a flatbed scanner. The depicted dimensions were taken separately using a caliper, not by measuring on the image. The white inner area is the paper over an as-yet-unused adhesive pad; the material of the bracket is black-painted metal.

[image]

[Unprocessed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S1J3.jpg)